# Is it true that $\mid f(z)\mid^2=f(z)\overline{f(z)}?$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Is this true? I thought it could be used to prove that $\mid \cosh(z)\mid^2=\sinh^{2}(x)+\cosh^{2}(y)$

Comment: It's true for any complex number yes $$|w|^2 = w\bar{w}$$

Comment: Is it true for even a complex-valued function? why is that?

Comment: Sure, $f(z)$ is a complex number (for every $z$ in your domain).

Comment: @DougL, Your statement is $\mid \cosh(z)\mid^2=\sinh^{2}(x)+\cosh^{2}(y)$, but it looks like $\mid \cosh(z)\mid^2=\sinh^{2}(x)+\cos^{2}(y)$. Two different functions are $\cosh^{2}(y)$ and $\cos^{2}(y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can provide the concrete example:
$$
z=(1-i),\implies\text{ the complex conjugate relatively of }z \text{ will be }{\bar{z}=(1+i)}.
$$
Therefore, for $\mid{f(z)}\mid^2=f(z)\bar{f}(z)$ we will have:
$$
\mid{f(z)}\mid^2=\mid{z}\mid^2=\mid{(1-i)}\mid^2=\left(\sqrt{(x^{2}+y^{2})}\right)^{2}=\left(\sqrt{(1^{2}+1^{2})}\right)^{2}=2,
\\
f(z)\bar{f}(z)=z\bar{z}=(1-i)(1+i)=2.
$$
This statement $\bbox[lightgreen]{\mid{f(z)}\mid^2=f(z)\bar{f}(z)}$  is true also for your case $\bbox[yellow]{\mid\cosh(z)\mid^2=\sinh^{2}(x)+\cos^{2}(y)}$:
$$
\bbox[pink]{\cosh(z)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^z+e^{-z}\right)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{x+yi}+e^{-x-yi})=
\\
=\frac{1}{2}(e^x\cos y+ie^x\sin y+e^{-x}\cos y-ie^{-x}\sin y),
\implies
\\
\implies\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})\cos y + \frac{1}{2}(e^x-e^{-x})i\sin y=
\bbox[pink]{\cosh x\cos y+i\sinh x\sin y}.
$$
Therefore, we can get the square of the absolute value of $\cosh(z)$:
$$
\bbox[lightblue]{{|\cosh(z)|}^2}=|\cosh(x+iy)|^2={(\cosh(x)\cos (y))}^2+{(\sinh(x)\sin(y))}^2=\bbox[lightblue]{{\cos}^2(y)+{\sinh}^2(x)}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

For any $z\in\Bbb{C}$, we can represent it as $z = a+bi$.

$$\lVert a + bi\rVert ^2 = a^2 + b^2$$
$$(a+bi)\overline{(a+bi)} = (a+bi)(a-bi) = a^2 -abi+abi-b^2i^2=a^2+b^2$$

So, for any $z$,

$$\lVert z \rVert^2=z\overline{z}$$

Then, assuming $f(z)\in\Bbb{C}$, we have

$$\lVert f(z) \rVert^2=f(z)\overline{f(z)}$$